# Why does cursor.clearselection() does not work in this example?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtextedit, qtextcursor

I am trying to create a button which underlines the selected text of my `QTextEdit` instance.

In the constructor, I am activating the cursor and setting a bool variable for the setFontUnderline method used later.

```
QTextCursor cursor1 = ui.myQTextfield->textCursor();
ui.myQTextfield->ensureCursorVisible();
test1 = false;
```

The first method below is executed by pressing the underline button and the second by releasing that.

```
void Hauptfenster::pressed_underlinebutton()
{
    test1 = true;
    ui.myQTextfield->setFontUnderline(test1);   
}

void Hauptfenster::released_underlinebutton()
{
    cursor.clearSelection();
    test1 = false;
    ui.myQTextfield->setFontUnderline(test1);
}
```

The problem is that with this code, the selected text first gets underlined by the pressed_underlinebutton() method and then instantly gets de-underlined with the released_underlinebutton method.

With the released_underlinebutton() method, I want to archieve that there is no more selection to de-underline while setting setfontunderline(false) again.

Comment: s/underles/underlines/?

Comment: Do you find any other grammar mistakes?

Comment: Well, you start several words with upper case. That is incorrect English, but that does not degrade the comprehension. `textfeld` is strange, too. ;-)

Comment: Your last two sentences are quite confusing to me. What are you trying to achieve; could you please rephrase? Is your problem that the selection is not cleared, i.e. `cursor.clearSelection();` not working? Is your problem that more than the selected gets underlined as per your comments under the deleted answer? I do not get it.

Comment: This works, but now I cannot access QTextedit anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using a QTextCursor copy

The documentation needs a bit more reading:

> [QTextCursor QTextEdit::​textCursor() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textCursor)
>
> Returns a copy of the QTextCursor that represents the currently visible cursor. Note that changes on the returned cursor do not affect QTextEdit's cursor; use setTextCursor() to update the visible cursor.

It writes that you get a copy, so when you try to change the text cursor features, you are operating on the copy rather than the original.

Therefore, you ought to make sure that if you want the changes to take effect on the text edit control, you need to set the text cursor back as follows:

```
cursor.clearSelection();
ui.myQTextfield->setTextCursor(cursor); // \o/
```

## Move the cursor of QTextEdit directly

[There is another way to solve this issue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#moveCursor), however.

```
QTextCursor::Left   9   Move left one character.
QTextCursor::End    11  Move to the end of the document.
```

So, you would be writing something like this:

```
ui.myQTextfield->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End)
ui.myQTextfield->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Left)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The moveCursor workaround solved my problem. Merry Christmas